# I am getting this error TypeError ("'int' object is not iterable",) using the reduce function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get the error when I Updated my code from

```
amount_recieved = 0
    for tx in tx_recipient:
        if len(tx) > 0:
            amount_recieved += tx[0]
```

to the reduce function

```
amount_recieved = functools.reduce(lambda tx_sum, tx_amt: tx_sum + sum(tx_amt[0]) if len(tx_amt) > 0 else 0, tx_recipient, 0)
```

Any light on what's wrong with this line would be helpful

Comment: could you give some sample data from tx_recipient where this error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` will take pairs of items from the iterable you supply (`tx_recipient`), therefore inside your lambda `tx_amt` is a single value so you can't do `tx_amt[0]`. Rewrite it like this:

```
amount_recieved = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, tx_recipient)
```

Comment: My issue was the square brackets on sum(tx_amt[0]) your method worked.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your loop is just summing numerical values at index 0 from each nested list in a list of lists (where the nested list contains at least one item). You are overcomplicating the one-line replacement function to get the same result by using `functools.reduce()`. All you need is `sum()`. For example:

```
amount_received = sum(tx[0] for tx in tx_recipient if len(tx))
```